# What is the name of operators that act on two equations?

Tags: logic, terminology

This is a math jargon question.

There are binary operators like "where" used to relate two equations. **Do these binary operators have a formal name?** As an example of what I mean, the statement

```
y = x^2 + b where x \in {5, 3, 1}
```

has a primary equation `y = x^2 + b` and a supplemental equation `x \in {5, 3, 1}`. Those are the two operands of the "where" operator. Similarly, the binary operator "for" appears in

```
f(x) = { 0 for x<0
       { 1 for 0<=x<=1
       { 0 for x>1
```

The LHS of the primary equation is `f(x)` and the RHS is an integer, with the value of the integer determined by the "for" operator and a supplemental inequality.

I am seeking a name for the category of relational operators that take equations/inequalities as operands.

Comment: Aren't they propositional connectives? Isn't your example an implication, from right to left?

Comment: The first statement also can be written as "for $x \in \{5,3,1\}$, let $y = x^2+b$". Moreover, you can substitute the word *for* with *if* in the second statement and the meaning are the same. I think this is more a matter of writing.

Comment: @bof - yes, a logical connective seems to fit. I have a layperson's understanding of "logical consequence", so I'm not clear that the statement is an implication since the right expression is not a logical consequence of the first.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - yes; I've corrected the text of my question.

Comment: @azif00 - I agree there are multiple equivalent ways of expressing the same statement. I'm seeking a label for the operator that connects two equations. I think bof's "logical connective" is a reasonable answer.

Comment: These are definitely not "logical connectives", this usually refers to logical operations like "and, or, not". The best fancy name I can come up with is "contextual (separators/denotators?)", although this is a stretch because they have no formal logical status. This is because these are linguistic devices that help us infer the logical context.

Comment: "since the right expression is not a logical consequence of the first" - bof said the opposite, that the left is a consequence of the right. If $x$ is in $\{5,3,1\}$, then $y=x^2+b$. If $0\leq x\leq1$, then $f(x)=1$.